# how to find and get an ::after or ::before of an element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

here is my code :

```
.back-div::after {
    background: black;
    content: "";
    opacity: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

how to get or find backdiv::after ??
please give the simplest way because I don't know even one library

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
let color = window.getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('.back-div'), ':after'
).getPropertyValue('color')
```

Comment: love U man 

Comment: @BehradMoosavi you're welcome, feel free to mark the question as correct if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the properties of the pseudo selector and a quick demo on how to switch classes (the best way to 'affect' css rules with pseudo selectors)

```js
let theStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.exciting-text'), ':after')
console.log(theStyle.content)
console.log(theStyle.color)

setTimeout(function() {
document.querySelector('.exciting-text').classList.add('boring-text')
document.querySelector('.exciting-text').classList.remove('exciting-text')
}, 1500)
```

```css
.exciting-text::after {
  content: " <- EXCITING!";
  color: green;
}

.boring-text::after {
  content: " <- BORING";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="boring-text">Here is some plain old boring text.</p>
<p class="exciting-text">Contributing to MDN is easy and fun.</p>
```